# How to link a draft in a Hexo post, that is not clickable until the draft is published?

Tags: hexo

I would like to link a draft from an existing post such that Hexo will only display its text content (not clickable) unless:

- it is run with `hexo --draft` (ergo 'display drafts' is enabled), or
- the draft is published (ergo becomes a regular post).

Example source:

```php
Flow automates projects to follow {% post_link flow-models 'git branching models' %}.
```

Assuming there is a draft called 'flow-models', the generated HTML is:

```html
<p>Flow automates projects to follow git branching models.</p>
```

After publishing the draft or with 'display drafts' enabled, the HTML is:

```html
<p>Flow automates projects to follow <a href="/drafts/flow-models">git branching models</a>.</p>
```

What actually happens in the given example is that Hexo generates a non-existing link with a current date (say today is April 9, 2023), that results into an error 404 (Not Found).

```html
<p>Flow automates projects to follow <a href="/2023/04/09/flow-models">git branching models</a>.</p>
```

Hope this makes sense. Thank y'all for your thoughts.